# Note taking software that supports images

Tags: software-recommendation

Is there a note taking software that supports image insertion? And best with font changing of area texts. I use tomboy before, that has no image support.

Thanks.

Comment: repos* :D. I've tried tomboy, by the way, and, when I have to have an image in mind, I just post its path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try [zim [image: Install zim]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/zim).

To install zim, run this command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install zim
```

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 2):

What about cherry-tree.. ?? seems pretty complete to me.

Supports images and also syntax highlights (for developers)... 
cross-platform & portable (easy move the data between different machines/os ex:using dropbox)

http://www.giuspen.com/cherrytree/

Answer (score 1):

I use Nixnote and it supports images.

**Nixnote** (formerly Nevernote) is an open source clone of Evernote.

> Evernote makes it easy to remember things big and small from your
> everyday life using your computer, phone, tablet and importantly for
> you the web. For this solution you must use the Evernote (clipper)
> extension for Mozilla Firefox. (Available in Firefox Add-ons)

**Method**

When you browse the internet using Firefox and you come across a website that you want to keep for review (text and Pictures), the Evernote clipper will allow you to this.

When you install NixNote on Ubuntu desktop you can set it up to automatically synchronize with your Evernote note book. The result will be that all your websites that you want to review will be in the NixNote desktop software.

To install it, enter the following command

```
sudo apt install nixnote2
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Xournal++](https://github.com/xournalpp/xournalpp/). It supports inserting images in the notebook (click on the image icon in the toolbar), and changing their size.
[image]

[image]
It further supports annotating with mouse, text input from keyboard (including LATEX), and input from Wacom tablets.

To install its latest stable version in supported version of Ubuntu, use the following commands. The PPA supports Ubuntu 18.04+. It also hosts packages for ARM and PowerPC.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:apandada1/xournalpp-stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xournalpp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try basket note pads http://basket.kde.org/  It works really well.

Answer (score 0):

Simplenote is an easy way to keep notes, lists, ideas and more. Your  notes stay in sync with all of your devices for free. To install Simplenote in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install simplenote
```

To add images to Simplenote via markdown text follow these steps:

**Enable markdown**

1. Open the Simplenote desktop application.
2. Select *File* -> *Preferences*.
3. Select the *Writing* tab.
4. Enable Markdown by pushing the slider button to the right of *Enable Markdown*.
5. Click *Done*.

After enabling markdown, images can be added to a note and embedded with markdown text that has the following format:

```
![alt](https://path_to_image.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Turtl](https://turtlapp.com/) for note taking in Ubuntu. It is a secure, encrypted alternative to **Evernote**. Currently it is in beta but it has a lot of features. It is a *private place* to keep your notes, research, passwords, bookmarks, dream logs, photos, documents and anything else you want kept safe. It lets you share with others and does so in a way that keeps your unshared data safe. You control what you share with others and everything else stays completely private. It is very secure and will be even more feature-rich in near future. You can download its **.tar.bz2** file from [here](https://turtlapp.com/download/) and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [ThetaPad](http://thetapad.com), which supports image insertion.

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: Why do you do so?

Comment: Sorry , you are asking why do I recommend ThetaPad?

Comment: 2nd try: Why do you recommend this as a solution to the question being asked (how does that help).

Comment: The question sounds like "Is there a note taking software that supports image insertion? And best with font changing of area texts. I use tomboy before, that has no image support."? The solution that I recommended supports image insertion.