# Good application for taking notes on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation, notes, evernote

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Note taking software that supports images](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161921/note-taking-software-that-supports-images)

Is there a good note taking application in ubuntu like [Evernote](http://evernote.com/evernote/) exists for windows and Mac users.

Requirements for good applications:-

1. A thumbnail/list preview for all the created notes.
2. An integration with the email address so that we can view the notes anywhere anytime.
3. Any easy way to input text, video, pdf, images etc.

I have tried tomboy, basket notes. They aren't that good.

---

Edit: Trying to install nevernote from an external source. But it has not satisfiable libssl dependency

[image: dependency]

Further trying to install libssl gives the following error

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libssreflect-coq : Depends: coq-8.3pl3+3.12.1 but it is not installable
 libssreflect-ocaml : Depends: libcoq-ocaml-4zyg6 but it is not installable
 libssreflect-ocaml-dev : Depends: libcoq-ocaml-dev-4zyg6 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anything that I might be doing wrong?

Comment: thanks for redirecting me to a link very helpful and indeed the same what I wanted. :)

Comment: You may want to close this question by voting it to close. :)

Comment: user reminder note from here http://getremindernote.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [Everpad](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad) fits your needs.

[Iloveubuntu about Everpad](http://www.iloveubuntu.net/meet-everpad-evernote-unity-lens-enabled-desktop-integrated-client-ppa-available)

[Webupd8 about Everpad](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/everpad-integrates-evernote-with-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can see Evernote Replacements for Linux in [this link](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/322137-finding-evernote-replacements-for-linux) and also there is an open source clone of Evernote which called [NixNote (previously called Nevernote)](http://nevernote.sourceforge.net/) , In addition you Can Install Evernote (4) In Linux, using Wine ([see this link](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/you-can-finally-install-evernote-4-in.html)).